# PHP Login and Logout not working

Tags: php, session, web

I searched the whole internet to find a solution, but couldn't find one.
This is my problem: I made a site to login a user, create a session and the possibility to log out (of course). However, when I log in a user, I create a session, but the session just keeps going on and doesn't stop when I try to destroy it.

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- menu bar -->
    <?php if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) { ?>
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="producten.php">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="FAQ.php">Contact</a></li>
                <li style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="document.getElementById('logoutpop').style.display='block'"><a>My account</a></li>
                <li style="cursor: pointer;"><a href="logout_action.php">Log out</a></li>
                <ul style="float: right;">
                    <li ><a href="winkelmandje.php" >Shopping Bag</a></li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>

    <?php } elseif (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE){ ?>
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul >
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="producten.php">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="FAQ.php">Contact</a></li>
                <li style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="document.getElementById('loginpop').style.display='block'"><a>Log in</a></li>
                <ul style="float: right;">
                   <li ><a href="winkelmandje.php" >Shopping bag</a></li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <?php } else {}?>

    // other irrelevant html code
</body>
</html
```

**login_action.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

// server gegevens
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "db";

// Connect with server
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$email = "";
$password = "";


// Give connection error
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
else {

}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password']; 

    // check if filled in
    if(!empty($_POST['email'])) {

        // query in SQL
        $query = ("SELECT * FROM WebsiteUsers WHERE email='$email' AND pass='$password' ");
        // result
        $result = $conn->query($query);

        // check if result exists in database
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
        {

                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                {

                }

                // session variables
                $_SESSION['loggedin'] = $email;
                $_SESSION['message']="You are now logged in"; 

                header('Location: index.php');
                exit;           

        } 
        else 
        {
             // show some error      
        }               

    }

}

$conn->close(); 


?>
```

**logout_action.php**

```
<?php

session_start();
session_destroy(); 
header("Location: index.php");
exit; 

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `session_status()` to check if the user is logged in. 
But according to the docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE is true when a session is started. You create a session at the beginning of the home page using `session_start()` even tho the user isn't logged in he's still starting a session. So you need to set a variable in the session itself stating if the user passed the login or not.

Also:

- You're storing your passwords in plain text, don't do that use Bcrypt or a diferent algorithm
- Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, learn about prepared statements and use them http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php don't under any circumstances use your current code in a production environment

Comment: should I use 'isset' instead?

Comment: You set the `$_SESSION['email']` variable when a person is logged in. So yes you could use `isset($_SESSION['email']);` to evaluate wether a person is logged in or not!

Comment: That still won't do it, do I need to include login_action.php somewhere?

Comment: Are you even able to log in?

Comment: Yes, when I register an account I can login, but the changes (so changing the menu bar) after the login are not being done.

Comment: I'm so stupid.. haha, just forgot to add 'login_action.php' to the action"" tag in the form. However your solution worked! Thank you!